# How to integrate expression with absolute value in it?

Tags: calculus

$f(x)={{\left| 1-x \right|}^{-0.5}}\exp (-{{\left| 1-x \right|}^{0.5}})$ for $x>0$

I was thinking to do a u-sub, 
$u={{\left| 1-x \right|}^{0.5}}$

but what would your $du$ be?

should I consider the negative sign inside the absolute value?

Comment: One definition of the absolute value is that abs($x$) $=x,$ if $x>0$ or $-x$ if $x<0.$ Try to determine where the terms inside the absolute value change sign. Once you've done this, you can break up the integral at those places and remove the absolute values.

Comment: Already did, final answer below, is that correct? if so, why doesn't it sum to 1?  I know it is suppose to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $u=\sqrt{|1-x|}$, then in fact $$u=\begin{cases}
\sqrt{1-x},&\text{if }x\le 1\\\\
\sqrt{x-1},&\text{if }x>1\;,
\end{cases}\tag{1}$$

since by definition $$|1-x|=\begin{cases}
1-x,&\text{if }1-x\ge 0\\\\
-(1-x)=x-1,&\text{if }1-x<0\;.
\end{cases}$$

Thus, $$du=\begin{cases}
-\frac12(1-x)^{-1/2}dx,&\text{if }x<1\\\\
\frac12(x-1)^{-1/2}dx,&\text{if }x>1\;.
\end{cases}\tag{2}$$

Thus, you’ll need to split the integral in two, one for $x<1$ and one for $x>1$. (Why did I change $x\le 1$ in $(1)$ to $x<1$ in $(2)$?)

Comment: Hey, Brian.  Thanks, it's pretty clear. I got a question on the $du$ part, where I got without the negative sign $$\[\frac{1}{2}{{(1-x)}^{\frac{1}{2}}}dx\]$$, did you let your u be the absolute value without negative signs?

Comment: @user1061210: I used $u$ as in $(1)$, so that there’s a factor of $-1$ from $(1-x)'$ in the derivative of the $x<1$ part.

Comment: $$F(a)=\int{f(x)dx }=\left\{ \begin{array}{*{35}{l}}
   \frac{1}{2}{{e}^{-{{\left( 1-a \right)}^{0.5}}}}-\frac{1}{2}{{e}^{-1}} & 0<a\le 1  \\
   1-\frac{1}{2}{{e}^{-{{(a-1)}^{0.5}}}}-\frac{1}{2}{{e}^{-1}} & 1<a  \\
\end{array} \right.\
$$
I got the above answer after integration, it's a cumulative function, which should sum to 1, but it doesn't, do you know what's wrong with it?

Comment: Working rather hastily, I get $4-\frac2{e}$. Don’t forget that $dx=2u du$, so that you’re integrating $2e^{-u}du$.

Comment: I figured it out, thanks everyone for trying to help.

Comment: Is it necessary that the two primitives has the same limit when approaching 1?